# Trying to avoid redundancy with a function and an async coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have this function:

```
def check_for_throttling(r):
    if r.status_code == responses.THROTTLING:
        #<lots of other stuff>
        time.sleep(Throttle.DELAY)
        Throttle.DELAY = Throttle.DELAY + 2
    return r
```

I also have this async coroutine:

```
async def check_for_throttling(r):
    if r.status_code == responses.THROTTLING:
        #<lots of other stuff>
        await async.sleep(Throttle.DELAY)
        Throttle.DELAY = Throttle.DELAY + 2
    return r
```

My question - is there a way to use one block of code for both scenarios?

I have other situations that have more complex logic than the example.

And all those situations, I have a function and an async coroutine that are identical except that one has `time.sleep()` and the other uses `async.sleep()`

Thank you!

Comment: I don’t understand why can’t you make a function `do_if_throttled` and call it from the code above?

Comment: ```time.sleep``` rather breaks the concept of an event loop, so perhaps find a way to delete that one all together. I found switching from ```requests``` to ```aiohttp``` helped, assuming this is what you are doing.

Comment: If `#<lots of other stuff>` is identical in the two cases, then it means its not doing any blocking activity. You could pull that code out and keep these two wrappers for the different ways to do things.

Answer (score 0):

The "obvious thing to do" there is to write the asyncio version of your code, and, if you have a sync thread or sync-block, to have a created loop on that thread, and call `loop.run_until_complete(async_check_for_throtling())` on that code.

If you are on a thread that is not using an asyncio loop for nothing else, as long as you keep a loop around "idle" doing this is not different from doing a synchronous call.

It is otherwise complicated to have code that can be called in both sync and async ways, because async code must return immediately an awaitable object when called. And simply writing the "await" keyword inside a function makes it automatically an async function - so there is no way to have an "if" that will take either code path.

**but if one insists**

Even writing it as a class whose instances would have the common code in certain methods, and the async-code and sync code separated in others, will have several limitations on the form that can take - but it can be done:

```
class CheckTrottling:
    def core(self, r):
        if r.status_code == responses.THROTTLING:
            #<lots of other stuff>
            yield
        
        Throttle.DELAY = Throttle.DELAY + 2
        return r
    async def async_check(self, r):
        runner = self.core(r)
        next(runner)
        await asyncio.sleep(...)
        try:
            next(runner)
        except StopIteration as stop:
            value = stop.value
        return value
    def check(self, r):
        runner = self.core(r)
        next(runner)
        time.sleep(...)
        try:
            next(runner)
        except StopIteration as stop:
            value = stop.value
        return value
```

You then instantiate the class (it can be a single, module level instance), you can call either the async_check or check method as desired.

In this model the main function will "pause" at the yield expression, and be resumed on a following `next` call - so it can be driven by an external function which can then be sync or async, and do whatever mode of "sleep" it prefers.

However, as it can be seen, this is essentialy replicating the very logic of asyncio to start with. (Back in Python 3.4, the first version of asyncio would use "yield", as the keywords for async code were not in the language yet). It is easy to perceive them that my first recommendation above, of writing the common code as async in the first place, should e the preferred way to go.